# Terraform - How to find Azure Kubernetes AKS vnet ID for network peering

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, azure-virtual-network

I'm using a single Terraform script to deploy AKS and an Application Gateway. So far everything is working as expected, and the last thing I need is to configure vnet peering between AKS and the Application Gateway.

According to Terraform's docs, vnet peering requires the AKS vnet name and ID:

```
# AppGw to AKS
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "appgw_aks_peering" {
  name                      = "appgw-aks-peer"
  resource_group_name       = "my-appgw-rg"
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.my_vnet.name
  remote_virtual_network_id = ???
}

# AKS to AppGw
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "aks_appgw_peering" {
  name                      = "aks-appgw-peer"
  resource_group_name       = "my-aksnode-rg"
  virtual_network_name      = ???
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.my_vnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name                = "my-aks"
  location            = "australiaeast"
  resource_group_name = "my-aks-rg"
  node_resource_group = "my-aksnode-rg"

  addon_profile {
    ingress_application_gateway {
      enabled    = true
      gateway_id = azurerm_application_gateway.my_appgw.id
    }
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name                 = "np01"
    node_count           = 1
    os_disk_size_gb      = 30
    vm_size              = var.aks_np_vm_sku
  }

  ...
}
```

The problem I have is the AKS vnet is automatically created when AKS is created, and neither the name or ID are exported anywhere. I can't find a way to get the AKS vnet name or ID with Terraform. Can someone point me in the right direction or suggest an alternate solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it’s not possible to get the Vnet ID from the resource block of the AKS cluster, you can create a vnet and subnet for the AKS as well and use it while creating the cluster in default node pool block like below:

```
default_node_pool {
    name                 = "np01"
    node_count           = 1
    os_disk_size_gb      = 30
    vm_size              = var.aks_np_vm_sku
    vnet_subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.aks.id
  }
```

So, as per your requirement the .tf file will be something like below:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "name" {
  name = "resourcegroupname"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks" {
  name                = "aks-vnet"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "aks" {
  name                 = "aks-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.location
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "appgw" {
  name                = "appgw-vnet"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
  address_space       = ["10.254.0.0/16"]
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "frontend" {
  name                 = "frontend"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.254.0.0/24"]
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "backend" {
  name                 = "backend"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.254.2.0/24"]
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "example-pip"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.location
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}
#&nbsp;since these variables are re-used - a locals block makes this more maintainable
locals {
  backend_address_pool_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.name}-beap"
  frontend_port_name             = "${azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.name}-feport"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.name}-feip"
  http_setting_name              = "${azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.name}-be-htst"
  listener_name                  = "${azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.name}-httplstn"
  request_routing_rule_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.name}-rqrt"
  redirect_configuration_name    = "${azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.name}-rdrcfg"
}
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network" {
  name                = "example-appgateway"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.location
  sku {
    name     = "Standard_Small"
    tier     = "Standard"
    capacity = 2
  }
  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "my-gateway-ip-configuration"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.frontend.id
  }
  frontend_port {
    name = local.frontend_port_name
    port = 80
  }
  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
  backend_address_pool {
    name = local.backend_address_pool_name
  }
  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = local.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    path                  = "/path1/"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 60
  }
  http_listener {
    name                           = local.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }
  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = local.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
  }
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "appgw_aks_peering" {
  name                      = "appgw-aks-peer"
  resource_group_name       = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.id
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.aks.id
}
# AKS to AppGw
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "aks_appgw_peering" {
  name                      = "aks-appgw-peer"
  resource_group_name       = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.aks.id
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.appgw.id
}
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name                = "my-aks"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.name.name
   dns_prefix              = "dns-myaks"
  addon_profile {
    ingress_application_gateway {
      enabled    = true
      gateway_id = azurerm_application_gateway.network.id
    }
  }
  default_node_pool {
    name                 = "np01"
    node_count           = 1
    os_disk_size_gb      = 30
    vm_size              = "Standard_D2_v2"
    vnet_subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.aks.id
  }
    identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. I was able to adopt your recommendation into my Terraform script and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it’s only possible to get the subnet id from the Kubernetes resource. The best way is to create a vnet and a subnet with Terraform and assign your Kubernetes to this subnet. Then you can add the peering.

```
# AppGw to AKS
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "appgw_aks_peering" {
  name                      = "appgw-aks-peer"
  resource_group_name       = "my-appgw-rg"
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.my_vnet.name
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.aks.id
}

# AKS to AppGw
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "aks_appgw_peering" {
  name                      = "aks-appgw-peer"
  resource_group_name       = "my-aksnode-rg"
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.aks.name
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.my_vnet.id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for readers who want to find out which Virtual Network your AKS cluster belongs to.

Run this command,

`az aks show -g portal-eu -n xxxxxx` and then look for `networkProfile.vnetSubnetId` in the returned JSON.

Where `xxxxxx` is the cluster name.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some fiddling. It'll only work if you have one aks vnet though as the code looks for a vnet containing the string 'aks-vnet-'.

```
# ---------------------------------------------- #
# Get the spoke vnet.
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vn" {
  name                = "vnet-prd-spoke-nteu-01"
  resource_group_name = "rg-core-01"
}
# ---------------------------------------------- #
# Get the aks vnet.
resource "null_resource" "nr" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<COMMAND
      az login --service-principal --tenant $env:ARM_TENANT_ID --username $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID --password $env:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
      $vnet = (az network vnet list --query "[?contains(name, 'aks-vnet-')].name" -o tsv)
      $vnet | set-content -path "${path.module}/vnet.txt" -force
      $vnetid = (az network vnet show --resource-group ${var.tw5_resource_group_aks} --name $vnet --query 'id' --output tsv)
      $vnetid | set-content -path "${path.module}/vnetid.txt" -force
    COMMAND
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
}
data "local_file" "vnet" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.nr]
  filename   = "${path.module}/vnet.txt"
}
data "local_file" "vnetid" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.nr]
  filename   = "${path.module}/vnetid.txt"
}
# ---------------------------------------------- #
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "vnp_a" {
  name                         = "spoke-to-aks"
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vn.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name         = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vn.name
  remote_virtual_network_id    = trimspace(data.local_file.vnetid.content)
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = true
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "vnp_b" {
  name                         = "aks-to-spoke"
  resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_aks
  virtual_network_name         = trimspace(data.local_file.vnet.content)
  remote_virtual_network_id    = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vn.id
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = true
}
# ---------------------------------------------- #
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster associated virtual network (VNet) details. I linked the AKS cluster with its VNet by adding a tag during AKS creation. A workaround involves running a script after AKS creation to find the VNet using the tag, and the details(Vnet name, Resource gp) are saved to a file. Later, the file is read to extract the VNet information, which is then used in configuring network peering. Below are the code snippets, I hope it helps.

```js
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = lower("${var.aks_resource_type}${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}")
  kubernetes_version  = var.aks_version
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = lower("${var.aks_resource_type}${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}")
  sku_tier            = var.setup[var.environment_tag].aks_sku_tier

  default_node_pool {
    zones               = var.availability_zones
    type                = var.aks_node_pool_type
    name                = var.aks_node_pool_name
    node_count          = var.setup[var.environment_tag].aks_node_count
    vm_size             = var.setup[var.environment_tag].aks_vm_size
    enable_auto_scaling = var.setup[var.environment_tag].aks_enable_auto_scaling
    min_count           = var.setup[var.environment_tag].aks_auto_scaling_min_count
    max_count           = var.setup[var.environment_tag].aks_auto_scaling_max_count
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  network_profile {
    load_balancer_sku = "standard"
    network_plugin    = "kubenet"
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment_tag,
    aks-cluster-name = lower("${var.aks_resource_type}${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}")
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rg,
  ]
}
```

```js
resource "null_resource" "retrieve_vnet_info" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      echo "AKS Cluster Name: ${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.name}"
      # Get the VNet name and resource group name based on the AKS cluster name tag
      vnet_info=$(az resource list --tag "aks-cluster-name=${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.name}" --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks'].{ResourceGroup: resourceGroup, VNetName: name}" --output json)

      # Output the VNet info to a file for later use
      echo "$vnet_info" > vnet_info.json

      # Display the content of vnet_info.json for testing
      cat vnet_info.json
    EOT
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks,
  ]
}
```

```js
data "local_file" "vnet_info" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.retrieve_vnet_info]
  filename   = "vnet_info.json"
}
```

Finally use the retrieved values as below

```js
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "example-2" {
  name                      = "peer"
  resource_group_name       = jsondecode(data.local_file.vnet_info.content)[0]["ResourceGroup"]
  virtual_network_name      = jsondecode(data.local_file.vnet_info.content)[0]["VNetName"]
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.example-1.id
}
```